# Hook up High Temperature Sensor with BBG and python?

Tags: python, beagleboneblack

I am new to the BBG/Grove things and posted my original question at [www.seeed.cc](https://www.seeed.cc/High-Temperature-Sensor-with-BBG-and-python%3F!-t-11685.html). However I decided to post it here as well for a broader audience.

I purchased a BBG and cape and tried to hook up the [High Temperature Sensor](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-High-Temperature-Sensor-p-1810.html) and want to do everything else in python.

With the following code ([from here](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/adc))...

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC 
ADC.setup()   

value_1 = ADC.read("P9_39")    
value_1_raw = ADC.read_raw("P9_39")
value_2 = ADC.read("P9_40")    
value_2_raw = ADC.read_raw("P9_40")

def printout():    
        print 'value_1:', value_1    
        print 'value_1_raw:', value_1_raw    
        print 'value_2:', value_2    
        print 'value_2_raw', value_2_rawhere
```

...I got those values:

```
value_1: 0.0688644722104 
value_1_raw: 283.0
value_2: 0.288400501013
value_2_raw 1181.0
```

What are those numbers/units exactly and most importantly, how are they connected?

Moreover I took the C++-code from the *Hight_Temp.cpp* ([here](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove_HighTemp_Sensor)) as orientation for a python script, but the results from those calculations turned out to be some weird values to me which I can not interpret.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` reads the voltage value scaled between 0 to 1. To get to the real voltage multiply it by 1.8V. so for example, P9_40, actual voltage is 0.288*1.8 = 0.5184 V (this is mentioned at the bottom of the https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/adc)

`read` and `read_raw` are similar except they are scaled by a constant factor (I saw that in the c code). The constant factor seems to be 4095.0, ie. 283.0/4095.0  = 0.0688. you can see the source code for read (*py_read) and read_raw (*py_read_raw) from the c code here https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/blob/master/source/py_adc.c

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying!

Comment: (But 283.0/4095.0=0,0691?)
However, at https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/adc it is said to reduce the 3.3V to the 1.8V with e.g. a resistor divider. As I haven't done that, I did not assume that I can apply this straight away. Is this done by the cape or the LMV358?

Comment: can u explain to me what you are measuring and what components are placed between your sensor and beagble bone?

Comment: Sure, I got the BBG with a [Cape](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove_Cape_for_BeagleBone_Series) and the sensor as mentioned above, this comes with its amplifier. This amp is connected via 4pin cable to the cape's J3 for ADC. The readings posted in the questions are at room temperature.

Comment: ok. I think if your sensor outputs voltage between 0-3.3V, first you need to convert it to 0-1.8V with resistor divider, then feed it to bbg adc, use the read command (dont need the read_raw), read will return a value between 0-1 to get the real voltage (rv1) which the adc sees multiply read*1.8, to get the voltage on the input side of resistor divider (or output side of sensor), you need to multiply rv1*(3.3/1.8). hope that helps.

Comment: If you think this answer has helped you solve your problem. Please upvote or/and accept this answer.